# Web App to run Python Scripts - Run as a background process.

Tags: python, web-applications, wsgi

I have a python script which i want a user to run in the server, with out giving a SSH Login permission. I got a web app from below link.
[How to connect a webpage with python to mod_wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122770/how-to-connect-a-webpage-with-python-to-mod-wsgi)

Here is the modified version that's working for me

---

```
 import web

    class Echo:
        def GET(self):
            return """<html><form name="script-input-form" action="/" method="post">
    <p><label for="Import"><font color=green><b>Press the button to import CSV</b></font)</label>
    Import: <input type="submit" value="ImportCSV"></p>
    </form><html>"""

    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
        return data
        obj = compile('execfile("importcsv.py")', '', 'exec')
        result = eval(obj, globals(), locals())
        web.seeother('/')
urls = (
  '/.*', Echo,
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
else:
    app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

---

Script i stored in site.py and I am executing it with the command "**python2.7 site.py 10.10.10.19:8080**". When user access 10.10.10.19:8080 he can see the web page and click on the button when he wants the code to be executed.

Now the issues is 
Web Page Stops when i close my SSH Session :( 
How do i run it in the background? tried & and that didn't help.

Thanks and Regards,
Rijil Hari

Comment: Is the server running Windows or *nix?

Comment: Not Windows, it's Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to spawn a new process, since the current process is attached to the shell (alternatively, you could detach the terminal from the ssh session).

To spawn a new process you can refer to [bash spawn new process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429763/new-application-process-from-bash-shell), or you can try [this option instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) which keeps your session alive after you disconnect.

Comment: Hi Just Tried Screen. Command ,which is working find on my session is giving below error on screen. (Unable to post the full error here)                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adminsite.py", line 75, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 313, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
/wsgi.py", line 54, in runwsgi
/httpserver.py", line 157, in runsimple
/__init__.py", line 1753, in start
    raise socket.error(msg)
socket.error: No socket could be created